# r fill and alpha from table

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha, fill

Is it possible to get a graph like the following with ggplot2 in R?

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=discrete_1, y=continuous_1)) +
 geom_violin(aes(fill=discrete_2, alpha=continuous_2)) +
 facet_grid(. ~ discrete_3)
```

Trying this, it seems their either 'alpha' or 'fill' will override each other?

I'm open to a different solution that achieves the same result (adding alpha to the fill colours proportionally to the value of continuous_2). My values for continuous_2 are always the same across rows with matching values for discrete_2.

Sorry if this is duplicate, I couldn't find anything that addressed this specifically.

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and your expected output. If you cannot post your data, then please post code for creating representative data.

Comment: `fill` and `alpha` work together. One will not overwrite the other. Also you ask, "Is it possible to get a graph like the following with ggplot2 in R?" but you have posted `ggplot2` code...